# C# How to Detect Alt+Enter in from Excel cell and import to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I'm importing a cell from Excel that have Alt+Enter to SQL Server.
For example(content of an Excel cell):

```
The Divided States of America
President
Donald
Trump
Make America Great Again
```

But when I import this cell into SQL Server: potus nvarchar(100), the content will be:

```
The Divided States of AmericaPresidentDonaldTrumpMake America Great Again
```

But I want to import, for example this string to potus cell:

```
The Divided States of America@Presiden@tDonald@Trump@Make America Great Again
```

Because I want to detect "@" symbol when I load data from SQL server to DataGridView. Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Can you show us the code/steps you used in importing them?

Comment: If you use a Stored Procedure or an SQL insert with parameterized commands the new lines will be inserted. You can use `string.substring` and `string.IndexOf` with America and Make to work out which newlines to replace with @'s

Comment: Do you want to detect "enter", "@" or to replace "enter" with "@"?

Comment: I want to to replace "enter" with "@". Can you tell me how to do this in SQL?